# Creating a popup box when the page loads

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a popup box to show up once the page has loaded. Does anyone know of a good tutorial that can help with this.

Comment: look at http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jquery](http://jquery.com) to know when the page is loaded, and alert() to pop up a box ([see here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)), like this:

In your HEAD section:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In your BODY section:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   alert("Hello")
});
```

Comment: Yep that was what I actually needed. I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do something on page load with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // do something
});
```

To open a popup use the `window.open()` javascript function : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp.

Answer (score 0):

as @Liam Sorsby suggested you can use [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

here is a simple example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $.colorbox({width:"30%", inline:true, href:"#subscribe"});
    }); 
</script>
<div id='subscribe' title='sub' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
    <p><strong>Light box test wellcom to help.</strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/NZ5qJ/2/)